# Make a model field as required on the base of a condition in Django Models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0

I'm working on a project with **Python(3.6)** and **Django(2.0)** in which I need to make a field in child model required on the base of a condition for a field in parent model class.

If the **service** is multiple then the **routing** and **configuration** fields will be required otherwise it's not necessary to be filled.

**Here's my code from models.py**

> From models.py:

```
services = (
    ('Single', 'Single'),
    ('Multiple', 'Multiple'),
)


class DeploymentOnUserModel(models.Model):
    deployment_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, )
    credentials = models.TextField(blank=False)
    project_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    project_id = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
    cluster_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=False)
    zone_region = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=False)
    services = models.CharField(max_length=150, choices=services)
    configuration = models.TextField(blank=True)
    routing = models.TextField(blank=True)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if self.services == 'Multiple' and not self.routing and not self.configuration:
            raise ValidationError("You must have to provide routing for multiple services deployment.")
        super().save(**kwargs)
```

> From serializers.py:

```
class DeploymentOnUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = DeploymentOnUserModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

> From apiview.py:

```
class DeploymentsList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = DeploymentOnUserModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DeploymentOnUserSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = DeploymentOnUserSerializer(data=self.request.data)
        validation = serializer.is_valid()
        if validation is True:
            perform_deployment(self.request.data)
            self.create(request=self.request)
        else:
            return Response('You haven\' passed the correct data ')
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

> Post payload:

```
{
  "deployment_name": "first_deployment",
  "credentials":{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "project_id",
  "private_key_id": "private_key_id",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY",
  "client_email": "client_email",
  "client_id": "client_id",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "client_x509_cert_url"
},
  "project_name": "project_name",
  "project_id": "project_id",
  "cluster_name": "numpy",
  "zone_region": "europe-west1-d",
  "services": "Single",
  "configuration": "",
  "routing": ""
}
```

> **Update:** Now I have implemented apiview and serializers for these models. When I submit a post request with the `services=Single` without the values for `configuration & routing` it returns `You haven't passed the correct data.`

This means the save method, is not working.
Help me, please!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are using [DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/), you can use [serializer validators](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/)

Comment: can you write the example? please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apart from my comment, you could override the `save()` method of `AwdModel` model.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class AwdModel(UserAccountModel):
    source_zip = models.FileField(upload_to='media/awdSource/', name='awd_source')
    routing = models.TextField(name='routing', null=True)

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and self.services == 'Multiple' and not self.routing:
            raise ValidationError("error message")
        super().save(**kwargs)
```

`self.id` will be `null` or similar if it's a new instance,hence the validation checks happens only if instance is created

**Update-1** use this payload to POST

```
{
  "deployment_name": "first_deployment",
  "credentials":{"test_key":"test_value"},
  "project_name": "project_name",
  "project_id": "project_id",
  "cluster_name": "numpy",
  "zone_region": "europe-west1-d",
  "services": "Single",
  "configuration": "",
  "routing": ""
}
```

**update-2**
try this for your serializer,

```
class DeploymentOnUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    credentials = serializers.JSONField()
    class Meta:
        model = DeploymentOnUserModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Hi @JerinPeterGeorge, I have updated the question, take a look, please!

Comment: Mean post input object?

Comment: the JSON data you passed to the view

Comment: Also add output of `print(serializer.errors)` . (add that print() after `validation = serializer.is_valid()` this statement)

Comment: `serializer.error` prints `{'credentials': ['Not a valid string.']}`

Comment: look at `Update-1`

Comment: it still returns the same error and also `serializer.error` again said that `{'credentials': ['Not a valid string.']}`

Comment: Then replace `{"test_key":"test_value"}` dict with some text as `"some text"`

Comment: for `credentials: "some_text"` it didn't return any error.

Comment: I need to pass a json object for `credentials` .